# How is a pandas column of rows containing variable length and comma separated strings of values, stacked into separate values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm in the process of trying to separate specific values in a pandas column so that any "groups" of values become separate values.

The code I'm using to do this currently is as follows:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv('ctabuses.csv')
route_column = data['routes']

with open('results.csv', 'wt+') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for value in route_column:
        writer.writerow(value.split)
```

However, when I write the contents to a file it produces this:

```
126

121,123

1,7,X28,126,129,130,132,151

1,7,X28,126,129,130,151

1,7,X28,126,129,130

1,7,X28,126,129

1,3,4,7,J14,26,X28,126,129,132,143,147,148

7,126,132,143,147

1,7,X28,126,129

3,4,6,J14,26,143

1,7,X28,126,129,151

1,7,X28,126,129,130,134,135,136,151,156

125,126

126

126

126
```

I've searched and tried everything I can think of and keep getting the same result.

**Edit: Expected Result**
My expected output if I encounter a group of values like this:

```
1,7,X28,126,129,130,134,135,136,151,156
```

Should be:

```
1
7
X28
126
129
130
134
135
136
151
156
```

Which would then be used to import into a MySQL database.

Comment: Rather than using csvwriter, you may get a more consistent result with [`pd.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: try like `pd.read_csv('Inventory.csv', usecols=['col2', 'col2',]).fillna('')`

Comment: Hey Joel, can you post what you expect your output to be?

Comment: Hey @PeterDolan thanks for the comment and time. I've updated the question to reflect the expected output if I encounter a cluster of values.

Comment: It looks like you're only looping through the individual rows in the pandas series. If you want to loop through the elements in the row, you need a nested loop, something like `writer.writerow(i) for i in value.split()`

Comment: Hey Joel, thanks for updating things! So do you basically want every comma-delimited value to be on it's own line?

Comment: Hey Peter no problem. Yes, I'd like to have everything on a separate line if possible. The reason behind this is because I need to create a relationship table for my database. The comma separated fields make it hard to aggregate

Comment: Looks like you would want to add a second loop before writing the line out, something like "for subvalue in values.split(',')" maybe? Also, a "df.head()" to show your data would be helpful. Finally, you should be able to write to your MySQL db from pandas.

Answer (score 1):

**Imports:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Create DataFrame:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

df.head()

                              0
0                           126
1                       121,123
2   1,7,X28,126,129,130,132,151
3       1,7,X28,126,129,130,151
4           1,7,X28,126,129,130
```

**String to list:**

```
df_list = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row).str.split(','))

df_list.head()

                                       0
0                                  [126]
1                             [121, 123]
2   [1, 7, X28, 126, 129, 130, 132, 151]
3        [1, 7, X28, 126, 129, 130, 151]
4             [1, 7, X28, 126, 129, 130]
```

**List to long:**

```
df_long = df_list.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df_long

0     126
1     121
1     123
2       1
2       7
2     X28
2     126
2     129
2     130
2     132
2     151
3       1
3       7
3     X28
3     126
3     129
3     130
3     151
...
```

**Save to csv:**

```
df_long.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

**Final Program (4 lines):**

```
df = pd.read_csv('ctabuses.csv')
df_routes = df.routes.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row).str.split(','))
df_routes = df_routes.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row[0]), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df_routes.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```